# Particles equivalent to english 'about'

Tags: grammar, word-choice, particles

I am trying to learn how to say 'to talk/write/read about smth' in Japanese, since corrections natives make to my sentences seems not to be very consistent.
For example, let us consider a phrase 'I talked/read/wrote about pencils'. Particles I want to use are を and で.
With 'talked', it seems that 鉛筆を話した is just fine, because here topic kinda fits into my understanding of 'direct object', but 鉛筆を書いた would mean 'i drawed a pencil', while 鉛筆で書いた would mean 'i wrote with a pencil'. What would one use instead? I tried to search Dictionary of Basic Japanese Grammar for で, but with no success.

Comment: there are many ways to talk "about" something. Maybe you would find it interesting to look up the grammar form "～について"

Comment: ～に関して／～に関する might also be useful.

Answer (score 1):

について is what you are looking for.

It translates as 'concerning', 'regarding', 'about' etc. Your sentences would look something like:

> 鉛筆**について**話した。
>   鉛筆**について**書いた。

Check [p280 of *A Dictionary of Intermediate Japanese Grammar*](https://core6000.neocities.org/dojg/entries/300.html) for more details.